# Не создается таблица

Tags: java, mysql

Не создается следующая таблица в MySQL 5.5:

```
CREATE_LOGINS = 
    "CREATE_TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'logins'" +
            "('idLogin' MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
            "'name' CHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
            "'password' CHAR(30) NOT NULL," +
            "'roleId' MEDIUMINT NOT NULL," +
            "'email' CHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
            "'phone' CHAR(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
            "PRIMARY KEY('idLogin')" +
            ");";
```

Компилятор выбрасывает ошибку синтаксиса:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'CREATE_TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'logins'('idLogin' MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'` at line 1

Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE_TABLE
```

Подчеркивание уберите

Comment: Получилось, результат:

     public static final String CREATE_LOGINS = 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logins ( " +
     "idLogin INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
     "name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, " +
     "password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, " +
     "roleId INT NOT NULL, " +
     "email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, " +
     "phone VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, " +
     "PRIMARY KEY(idLogin) " +
     ");";